# Determine IF statement condition at runtime

Tags: java, runtime, conditional-statements

I have a function which accepts two parameters, `foo(A a, String type)` depending on type I have to change the `if` statement condition.

```
foo(A a, String type){
    //if type equals 'bar'
    if(!a.isEmpty() && a.hasMember()){...}
    //but if type is something else
    if(!a.isEmpty() || a.hasMember()){...}
}
```

the logic in the `if` body is the same pretty much everything else is the same except the condition is there any efficient way to implement the difference or I have to write everything twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the predicates with an `||` and make the check of `type` in each condition part.

```
if (type.equals("bar") && !a.isEmpty() && a.hasMember()) || (!type.equals("bar") && (!a.isEmpty() || a.hasMember())) {
  //do your thing
}
```

If `null` is a possible value of `type`, then it is possible to change the check to `"bar".equals(type)` to avoid a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: oh snap that's so simple, should've think of that myself :) thanks

Comment: @Tim We also need a check to test for null for `type` in this scenario.

Comment: Turn the `type.equals("bar")` statements around (`"bar".equals(type)`). If `type` could be of null value this will safe you some unneccessary NPE checks

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can use the following:

```
foo(A a, String type){
    //if type equals 'bar'
    if("bar".equals(type)) {
       if(!a.isEmpty() && a.hasMember()){...}
    }
    else  {
      //but if type is something else
      if(!a.isEmpty() || a.hasMember()){...}
    }
}
```

Explanation: If type has value "bar" then if condition becomes true and then whatever code you want for that condition will be executed.

You can also use concise form:

```
if( ("bar".equals(type) && (!a.isEmpty() && a.hasMember())) || (!"bar".equals(type) && (!a.isEmpty() || a.hasMember()))) {
  // Do your stuff  
}
```

The point to note is `"bar".equals(type)` is better than `type.equals("bar")` as it also saves you from hassle of the case when type is `null`.

Comment: Thanks for input, but that's exactly what I am trying to avoid, I am looking whether there is any other way to do it

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri: What do you mean by other way?

Comment: meaning that I don't want to repeat the body of my if statement twice

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri: In that case you can join the conditions. Check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a map with key type, and value should be object that have you type related logic.

```
foo(A a, String type) {
    typesMap.get(type).execute(a);
}


class TaskImpl implements Task { // each task should behave as it should be
    @override
    public void execute(A a) {
        if(!a.isEmpty() && a.hasMember()) {...}
    }
}
```